# How to call a method in a fragment through the onClick in another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I am building an app with 2 fragments.  The 1st fragment has an ImageView and 2 TextViews and the 2nd fragment has a set of buttons and EditTexts.  In the 2nd fragment, I have a button called "Save".  When this button is clicked, I want to download the image inside my 1st fragment to my device folder (The ImageView, the URI, the bitmap and canvas objects are all in the 1st fragment).

Because fragments can't communicate with one another directly, I was thinking of doing this with an interface.  What I did was:

- I've declared my interface in the 2nd fragment
- Applied the logic of the interface's method in the MainActivity (which is the shared activity between the 2 fragments)
- Fed the necessary parameters for the method in the 1st fragment.
- Didn't work

But I don't think that this was the correct order so it's no surprise that it didn't work.  How do I apply the interface in a way that a button click in the 2nd fragment downloads the image in the 1st fragment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try one of these three options:

**1.) Using callbacks to communicate via the activity**

As shown in [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating), you can define an interface in fragment 2 which is then called when the button is clicked. Your activity (which holds fragment 2) provides an implementation for that interface in which the activity calls a method in fragment 1 for downloading the image. For example:

**Fragment 1 providing the download method**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    OnButtonClickedListener mCallback;

    public void startImageDownload() {
        // Download the image
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Fragment 2 defining and calling the interface**

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    OnButtonClickedListener mCallback;

    // Some kind of init method called by onCreate etc. 
    private void init() {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Call the listener if present
                if(mCallback != null) {
                    mCallback.onButtonClicked();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setOnButtonClickedListener(Activity activity) {
        mCallback = activity;
    }

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnButtonClickedListener {
        public void onButtonClicked();
    }

    // ...
}
```

**The Activity reacting on the Button click and calling the download method**

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity implements Fragment2.OnButtonClickedListener {
    Fragment1 mFragment1;

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment instanceof Fragment2) {
            // Register the listener
            Fragment2 fragment2 = (Fragment2) fragment;
            fragment2.setOnButtonClickedListener(this);
        } else if (fragment instanceof Fragment1) {
            // Keep a reference to fragment 1 for calling the "download" method
            mFragment1 = (Fragment1) fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked() {
        // Handle the button click
        mFragment1.startImageDownload();
    }
}
```

This way you avoid linking the fragments together, instead you have the activity beeing a loose "connection" between fragment 1 and fragment 2.

This is just an exmple, i did not had time to test it. But i hope it helps.

**2.) Using a local broadcast**

I would recommend using the `LocalBroadcastManager` for sending a broadcast in fragment 1 (that the button was clicked) and receiving it in fragment 2 (downloading the image). [Here](https://android.jlelse.eu/local-broadcast-less-overhead-and-secure-in-android-cfa343bb05be) is a great article about local broadcasts.

**3.) Another option is to use ViewModel**

The `ViewModel` was recently introduced by the new Android Jetpack and "is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations." (from [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)).

*It can also be used to share data between two fragments*: Your activity basically holds the ViewModel and the fragments (inside that activity) can get access to it by calling: `ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);`
I think your scenario you could use Observers or some kind of LiveData to react to the button-click via a ViewModel.

Thanks to @Elletlar for helping me improve my answer.

Comment: Why is `LocalBroadcastManager` the preferred way?

Comment: Ignoring the implementation for a moment, what is the most important design consideration? Fragments should be independent modules that can be arranged in different activities. Having 1 fragment call an interface in another fragment is not advisable because they are too tightly coupled. You could have implemented that first example in such a way that the callback is called in the activity instead of coupling the fragments together.

Comment: @Elletlar I'd love to do it like that.  Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with this.

Comment: The way that Google currently recommend that you do this is to either use a ViewModel or route the data through the activity using callbacks [Communicate with other fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating). The majority of the samples on StackOverflow are low quality ones where 1 fragment directly calls into another, but it is better to take the time to learn to do it correctly.

Comment: But you will see developers using RxJava, EventBus, Broadcasts and other methods besides. But using Google's current recommendation ViewModel is the best approach for 2019. Regards.

Comment: Using a ViewModel means adding another dependency to your project (`androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel`). LocalBroascastManager is part of Android by default and would be straight forward for just calling a method in another fragment.

Comment: But, why does that matter? The Fragment class has recently been deprecated. Does that mean we should no longer use Fragments? Fragments are a core part of Android design even though they are located in the compatibility library which requires a dependency. Regardless, Google have spelled out how to handle this scenario. I think it would be good to review this material: [Communicate with other fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating). Regards.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for pointing that out. Would you @Elletlar prefer `ViewModel` over greenrobot's EventBus? I was thinking about that yesterday, because i need to transfer a List of objects from one fragment into another.

Comment: The advantage of ViewModel over other reactive frameworks is that it is [Lifecycle aware](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle). But I would probably be more likely to use RxJava/RxKotlin than EventBus for a few reasons: 1. Rx exists across a lot of languages and platforms 2.Advanced features: Filtering 3. As a contractor, I get a lot of interview questions regarding Rx 4. Searching for both terms on StackOverflow shows that RxJava/RxKotlin is more popular/trendy than EventBus. Having said that, I have always found EventBus to be reliable and solid..

Comment: @Sandrogo If you have time to update this answer with a sample from the guidelines. For example, have your fragment-B call a callback in the Activity. The callback in the activity can then call the desire method in fragment-A. [To avoid linking the fragments together] And/Or provide some basic info about ViewModel then I will upvote it when you are done. Regards.

Comment: @Elletlar I revised my answer.

Comment: I think I'll go with the `LocalBroadcastManager`.  It is more straight forward and less clutter.

About ViewModel.  I already have a ViewModel in my app but so far, I use ViewModels to pass data.  I don't know how to use the VIewModel to invoke a method in a fragment through the `onClick` in another fragment.

Comment: So my first answer was correct! It would be nice, if you could accept my answer and give it an upvote. I will edit it again and add LocalBroadcastManager as a third option tomorrow.

Comment: I added LocalBroadcastManager again.